# Logitech C270 webcam: no picture

Tags: windows-10, drivers, hardware-failure, webcam, logitech-webcam

I have a Logitech C270 webcam. I used it for years on my windows computer without issues. The video stopped working some weeks ago. Firefox and Skype say that some other program uses the camera. Windows Camera app shows black picture without any error message. The microphone works fine btw.

My first thought was that it is a Windows 10 issue:

- Windows 10 knows about the camera. Seemingly no problem in device manager.
- Tried out the possible workarounds listed on the internet:

  - switching to built-in drivers,
  - uninstall/reinstall device with logitech drivers,
  - different USB ports (2.0/3.0),
  - checking in process explorer if something is using the camera or its microphone,
  - deleted some files suggested somewhere in case of win 8/10 upgrade (which was not the case, but whatever works)

I was out of ideas, so I checked the camera with my Linux laptop. Again the laptop knows about the camera, but no picture, no errors. Based on this I guess it is a hardware issue. Before throwing the cam in the trash, I just want to ask if you think that I missed something.